# Large Switch Case (60 different Cases) - how do I reduce? or refine the code

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, switch-statement

so I have a switch case that takes the input of the length of a side (in CM) and selects how long to spin the robot wheel for (in ms) for example
user inputs 25 selects case 25 and sets the time to 2000ms

but having 60 different possible cases (twice) I am confused at how to shrink this down?
if it is possible

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;

public class assignment2 {
    static String shape,largestShapeName;
    static int side1,side2,side3;
    static int triangleCount=0,rectangleCount = 0;
    static int area,largestShape = 0;
    static int largestSide1,largestSide2,largestSide3;
    static int angle1,angle2,angle3;
    static boolean possible=false;
    static Scanner shapescanner = new Scanner(System. in);
    static Scanner sidescanner = new Scanner(System. in);
    static Finch myfinch = new Finch();
    static ArrayList<String> arrayShape = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        System.out.println("Please Enter The shape you want to Draw");

        shape = shapescanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        while (!"Q".equals(shape)){

        while (!"Q".equals(shape) && !"R".equals(shape) && !"T".equals(shape) ) {

                System.out.println(shape +" is an incorrect Option Please Enter again");
                shape = shapescanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        }
        if ("R".equals(shape)) {
            Rectangle();

        } else if ("T".equals(shape)) {
            Triangle();
        }
        if (area > largestShape) {
            if ("R".equals(shape)) {
                largestSide1=side1;
                largestSide2=side2;
                largestShapeName= "R";
            }else {
                largestSide1=side1;
                largestSide2=side2;
                largestSide3=side3;
                largestShapeName= "T";
            }
            System.out.println("Please Enter The shape you want to Draw");
            shape = shapescanner. nextLine().toUpperCase();
        }else {
        System.out.println("Please Enter The shape you want to Draw");
        shape = shapescanner. nextLine().toUpperCase();
        }
        }
        if ("Q".equals(shape)) {
             for (int i = 0; i < arrayShape.size(); i++) {
                  System.out.println(arrayShape.get(i));
                }
            myfinch.quit();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void Rectangle () {
        int side1time = 0;
        int side2time = 0;

        System.out.println("Please Enter The Length of first side");
        side1 = Integer.parseInt(sidescanner. nextLine());
        while (side1>80 || side1<20) {

            System.out.println(side1 +" is an incorrect Size Please Enter again");
            side1 = Integer.parseInt(sidescanner. nextLine());
    }
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Length of second side");
        side2 = Integer.parseInt(sidescanner. nextLine());
        while (side2>80 || side2<20) {

            System.out.println(side2 +" is an incorrect Size Please Enter again");
            side2 = Integer.parseInt(sidescanner. nextLine());
    }
        switch (side1) {
        case 20:  side2time = 2000 ;
        break;
        case 21:  side2time = 2000 ;
        break;
        case 22:  side1time = 2100 ;
        break;
        case 23:  side1time = 2200 ;
        break;
        case 24:  side1time = 2300 ;
        break;
        case 25:  side1time = 2400 ;
        break;
        case 26:  side1time = 2500 ;
        break;
        case 27:  side1time = 2600 ;
        break;
        case 28:  side1time = 2700 ;
        break;
        case 29:  side1time = 2800 ;
        break;
        case 30:  side1time = 2900 ;
        break;
        case 31:  side1time = 3000 ;
        break;
        case 32:  side1time = 3100 ;
        break;
        case 33:  side1time = 3200 ;
        break;
        case 34:  side1time = 3300 ;
        break;
        case 35:  side1time = 3400 ;
        break;
        case 36:  side1time = 3500 ;
        break;
        case 37:  side1time = 3600 ;
        break;
        case 38:  side1time = 3700 ;
        break;
        case 39:  side1time = 3800 ;
        break;
        case 40:  side1time = 3900 ;
        break;
        case 41:  side1time = 4000 ;
        break;
        case 42:  side1time = 4100 ;
        break;
        case 43:  side1time = 4200 ;
        break;
        case 44:  side1time = 4300 ;
        break;
        case 45:  side1time = 4400 ;
        break;
        case 46:  side1time = 4500 ;
        break;
        case 47:  side1time = 4600 ;
        break;
        case 48:  side1time = 4700 ;
        break;
        case 49:  side1time = 4800 ;
        break;
        case 50:  side1time = 4900 ;
        break;
        case 51:  side1time = 5000 ;
        break;
        case 52:  side1time = 5100 ;
        break;
        case 53:  side1time = 5200 ;
        break;
        case 54:  side1time = 5300 ;
        break;
        case 55:  side1time = 5400 ;
        break;
        case 56:  side1time = 5500 ;
        break;
        case 57:  side1time = 5600 ;
        break;
        case 58:  side1time = 5700 ;
        break;
        case 59:  side1time = 5800 ;
        break;
        case 60:  side1time = 5900 ;
        break;
        case 61:  side1time = 6000 ;
        break;
        case 62:  side1time = 6100 ;
        break;
        case 63:  side1time = 6200 ;
        break;
        case 64:  side1time = 6300 ;
        break;
        case 65:  side1time = 6400 ;
        break;
        case 66:  side1time = 6500 ;
        break;
        case 67:  side1time = 6600 ;
        break;
        case 68:  side1time = 6700 ;
        break;
        case 69:  side1time = 6800 ;
        break;
        case 70:  side1time = 6900 ;
        break;
        case 71:  side1time = 7000 ;
        break;
        case 72:  side1time = 7100 ;
        break;
        case 73:  side1time = 7200 ;
        break;
        case 74:  side1time = 7300 ;
        break;
        case 75:  side1time = 7400 ;
        break;
        case 76:  side1time = 7500 ;
        break;
        case 77:  side1time = 7600 ;
        break;
        case 78:  side1time = 7700 ;
        break;
        case 79:  side1time = 7800 ;
        break;
        case 80:  side1time = 7900 ;
        break;
        }
        switch (side2) {
        case 20:  side2time = 2000 ;
        break;
        case 21:  side2time = 2000 ;
        break;
        case 22:  side2time = 2100 ;
        break;
        case 23:  side2time = 2200 ;
        break;
        case 24:  side2time = 2300 ;
        break;
        case 25:  side2time = 2400 ;
        break;
        case 26:  side2time = 2500 ;
        break;
        case 27:  side2time = 2600 ;
        break;
        case 28:  side2time = 2700 ;
        break;
        case 29:  side2time = 2800 ;
        break;
        case 30:  side2time = 2900 ;
        break;
        case 31:  side2time = 3000 ;
        break;
        case 32:  side2time = 3100 ;
        break;
        case 33:  side2time = 3200 ;
        break;
        case 34:  side2time = 3300 ;
        break;
        case 35:  side2time = 3400 ;
        break;
        case 36:  side2time = 3500 ;
        break;
        case 37:  side2time = 3600 ;
        break;
        case 38:  side2time = 3700 ;
        break;
        case 39:  side2time = 3800 ;
        break;
        case 40:  side2time = 3900 ;
        break;
        case 41:  side2time = 4000 ;
        break;
        case 42:  side2time = 4100 ;
        break;
        case 43:  side2time = 4200 ;
        break;
        case 44:  side2time = 4300 ;
        break;
        case 45:  side2time = 4400 ;
        break;
        case 46:  side2time = 4500 ;
        break;
        case 47:  side2time = 4600 ;
        break;
        case 48:  side2time = 4700 ;
        break;
        case 49:  side2time = 4800 ;
        break;
        case 50:  side2time = 4900 ;
        break;
        case 51:  side2time = 5000 ;
        break;
        case 52:  side2time = 5100 ;
        break;
        case 53:  side2time = 5200 ;
        break;
        case 54:  side2time = 5300 ;
        break;
        case 55:  side2time = 5400 ;
        break;
        case 56:  side2time = 5500 ;
        break;
        case 57:  side2time = 5600 ;
        break;
        case 58:  side2time = 5700 ;
        break;
        case 59:  side2time = 5800 ;
        break;
        case 60:  side2time = 5900 ;
        break;
        case 61:  side2time = 6000 ;
        break;
        case 62:  side2time = 6100 ;
        break;
        case 63:  side2time = 6200 ;
        break;
        case 64:  side2time = 6300 ;
        break;
        case 65:  side2time = 6400 ;
        break;
        case 66:  side2time = 6500 ;
        break;
        case 67:  side2time = 6600 ;
        break;
        case 68:  side2time = 6700 ;
        break;
        case 69:  side2time = 6800 ;
        break;
        case 70:  side2time = 6900 ;
        break;
        case 71:  side2time = 7000 ;
        break;
        case 72:  side2time = 7100 ;
        break;
        case 73:  side2time = 7200 ;
        break;
        case 74:  side2time = 7300 ;
        break;
        case 75:  side2time = 7400 ;
        break;
        case 76:  side2time = 7500 ;
        break;
        case 77:  side2time = 7600 ;
        break;
        case 78:  side2time = 7700 ;
        break;
        case 79:  side2time = 7800 ;
        break;
        case 80:  side2time = 7900 ;
        break;
        }
        myfinch.setLED(0, 255, 0, 2000);
        myfinch.setWheelVelocities(100,100,side1time);
        myfinch.setLED(255, 0, 0, 200);
        myfinch.setWheelVelocities(100,0,2000);
        myfinch.setWheelVelocities(100,100,side2time);
        myfinch.setLED(255, 0, 0, 200);
        myfinch.setWheelVelocities(100,0,2000);
        myfinch.setWheelVelocities(100,100,side1time);
        myfinch.setLED(255, 0, 0, 200);
        myfinch.setWheelVelocities(100,0,2000);
        myfinch.setWheelVelocities(100,100,side2time);
        myfinch.setLED(255, 0, 0, 200);
        myfinch.setLED(0, 0, 0, 200);
        myfinch.setLED(255, 0, 0, 200);
        rectangleCount += 1;
        arrayShape.add(shape + ":" + side1 + "," + side2);
        System.out.println(arrayShape.get(0));
        area = side1 * side2;
    }
    public static void Triangle() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values to be assigned can change at a later point in time, you can fill a map with the key/value pairs and use that instead (you might put these values into a file and read that in, so you don't need to recompile the class if these values change):

```
private final static Map<Integer, Integer> SIDE2TIMEMap = new HashMap<>();

static {
    SIDE2TIMEMap.put(Integer.valueOf(20), Integer.valueOf(2000));
    SIDE2TIMEMap.put(Integer.valueOf(21), Integer.valueOf(2000));
    // [...]
    SIDE2TIMEMap.put(Integer.valueOf(80), Integer.valueOf(7900));
}
```

Later you can get the values like this:

```
private static int getTimeForSide(int side) {    
    Integer timeVal = SIDE2TIMEMap.get(Integer.valueOf(side));
    if (timeVal == null) {
        timeVal = Integer.valueOf(1000); // default value
        // alternatively: throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid side: " + side);
    }
    return timeVal.intValue();
}

[...]

    int side1time = getTimeForSide(side1);
    int side2time = getTimeForSide(side2);
```

Comment: the sidetimes will never change they are almost like a lookup table if you want to travel 20 cm the wheel should travel for x amount

Answer (score 4):

Your `switch(side1)` seems equivalent to:

```
if (side1 == 20) side2time = 2000;
if (side1 > 20 && side1 <= 80) side2time = (side1 - 1) * 100
```

The same applies to the other switch statement.

Comment: thank you! that does work with the values given, however, i must admit to them being placeholders as each distance must be tested and (20cm,21cm,22xm ++) by changing that ms value to get it to go the correct distance. the actual values are not as linear as just side1-1 *100 which would work with those values

Comment: @AliB2512 Please include those, and all other, requirements in your post. Rewriting code depends on the semantics you want/need. If you don't explain the semantics, we can't account for them in our answers.

Comment: @AliB2512 Either there is a formula to calculate sidetime or each value is arbitrary. In the first case, just include the formula in your code, in the second case, you will have to manually write all the possible values - using a switch could be replaced by a map but you will still have 60 lines of code.

Comment: @assylias, unfortunately, they are arbitrary all worked out from experimenting, and so I guess there is nothing I can do bar have that many lines of code